# Error publishing to bluemix. "Development Mode on"

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools, ibm-cloud-plugin

I'm trying to publish an application to bluemix.
1. I have enabled development mode. Right click the application -> Enable Development Mode.
2. I make a change in a servlet.
3. Right click on "Bluemix Server" -> Publish.

Then it throws the error: 'Publishing to IBM Bluemix...' has encountered a problem.
An internal error occurred during: "Publishing to IBM Bluemix..."

The details: An internal error occurred during: "Publishing to IBM Bluemix...".
com/ibm/cftools/branding/internal/CloudFoundryBluemixServer.isSso()Z

Eclipse Neon 4.6.0

I'm runing java:

```
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

IBM Bluemix tools: 1.0.13 v20160902_1659

the .log file:

```
  !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2016-11-11 10:52:27.692
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Publishing to IBM Bluemix...".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibm.cftools.branding.internal.CloudFoundryBluemixServer.isSso()Z
    at com.ibm.cftools.branding.internal.CloudFoundryBluemixServer.createServerConnection(CloudFoundryBluemixServer.java:254)
    at com.ibm.cftools.branding.internal.CloudFoundryBluemixServerBehaviour.publishModule(CloudFoundryBluemixServerBehaviour.java:562)
    at com.ibm.cftools.branding.internal.CloudFoundryBluemixServerBehaviour.publishModules(CloudFoundryBluemixServerBehaviour.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:987)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3172)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are hitting this issue you may either:

- Update your Eclipse dependencies to the latest provided by Eclipse Tools for Cloud Foundry (Eclipse CFT). In the workbench, select Help (menu item) > Check for Updates. This should provide you with a list of plug-ins to upgrade.
- Or, failing this, you may install Eclipse Neon.1 or higher to resolve the issue, as Eclipse Neon.1 includes the latest version of these dependencies.

Comment: With Neon 4.6.0 out of the box the versions are: "Cloud Foundry Tools Core" v1.0.4 and "Cloud Foundry Tools UI" v1.0.3. The new versions needed are "Cloud foundry tools UI" to v1.0.6 and "Cloud foundry tools core" to v1.1.0. With these new versions the publish worked fine.

Comment: Hi Jonathan now I realized that you said "Eclipse Neon.1". I thought it was a typo but you meant Neon 4.6.1, not 4.6.0 that is the one I installed. I guess in 4.6.1 the Eclipse CFT plugins were the ones needed.

Comment: Hi Jxadro, you are correct. Eclipse Neon.1 is the second Neon release of Eclipse, with the first being the Eclipse Neon GA version, and next month's being Eclipse Neon.2.  Previously Eclipse used the SR1 or SR2 designation, for example Mars SR2, but has switched to dot notation as of Neon.